# Couldn't find file .exe.manifest when hosting winforms application in browser

Tags: c#, wpf, hosting, manifest, web-hosting

i am hosting windows form application in webbrowser. when i run my application, it keep on telling couldn't find .exe.manifest file.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.3.9600.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34274 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34274 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
```

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/amalraj.umapathy/Downloads/WPFHost%20(6).xbap

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : WPFHost.xbap, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f79e6586c29e4e3f, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/amalraj.umapathy/Downloads/WPFHost.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [12/09/2015 5:37:20 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/amalraj.umapathy/Downloads/WPFHost.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindAsyncWorker()
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Downloads\WPFHost.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Please clarify me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess I'll ask the obvious,  do you have a manifest file in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have manifest file Ron.

Comment: I have manifest file in debug folder, but when i run my application through Visual Studio, .XBAP file is only downloaded. Its not running in new tab of browser, when i click that downloaded .XBAP file only, the application is running in browser, which tells couldn't find manifest file.